# Facebook Create ad Creative : Invalid parameter error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am working on the Facebook Marketing API and I am getting the error when I create ad creative. The error is the invalid parameter. I got the idea from the official documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/#create_example)

And here is my code

```
$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_331**********774');
$creative->setData(array(
   AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
   AdCreativeFields::TITLE => 'my title',
   AdCreativeFields::BODY => 'my body',
   AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => 'https://www.link.com',
   AdCreativeFields::LINK_URL => 'https://www.link.com',
   AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => '6fefe3bffe71af42892e64ac9768375e8s',
));
$creative2 = $creative->create();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($creative2->id); die;
```

Thanks in advance Please help.

Comment: Any other details about the error from the logs? Are you able to create via API with the console? check the image is owned by the AdAccount (See the doc about [How-to read image of an AdAccount](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image#Reading)

Comment: I solved this by adding catching the exception. Actually the image hash was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by catching the exception and it told me the error. The error was invalid image hash. I used the following code.

```
try {
   $this->_creative->setData($this->_postdata);
   $creative2 = $this->_creative->create();
   $this->_ad->setData(array(
       AdFields::NAME => $this->_postdata[AdFields::NAME],
       AdFields::ADSET_ID => $this->_adset,
       AdFields::CREATIVE => array('creative_id' => $creative2->id),
   ));
   $adresponse = $this->_ad->create(array(
        Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
  ));
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($adresponse);
} catch (RequestException $ex) {
       print_r($ex->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```